# How to read dump flow-capture from GO?

Tags: linux, go, netflow

The capture stream adds netflow v5 dumps to the server, when reading it from GO it is either simply impossible to read, because the first two bytes are not a version of netflow, or if I transfer the packet to 11 arrays, it gives the packet completely or also gives an error if it tries example output that should be, example output:

`0.0.0.10
157.121.64.85
138.166.72.38
107.207.29.71
108.177.99.171
243.117.126.147`
But netflow writes addresses in a dump which are behind NAT.
When working with flow-tools everything is displayed correctly, used various libraries to unmarshal into the structure, but the output is the same everywhere, the one indicated above.

```
    go func() {
    for f := range fileNamesCatalog{
      file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
      if err != nil{
        fmt.Errorf("Failed open file %v", f)
        continue
      }
      decoder := netflow.NewDecoder(session.New())
      body, err := decoder.Read(bytes.NewReader(file[11:]))
      switch packet := body.(type) {
      case *netflow5.Packet:
        filter(packet,net.ParseIP("157.121.64.85"),packetsChannel)
      }

    }
     }()
```

I am using two packages:
https://github.com/tehmaze/netflow
https://github.com/VerizonDigital/vflow